# get to/have got to - meanings

Tags: meaning

**1 I get to travel a lot in my job.** means "I have possibilities to travel in my job.

**2 I've got to travel to London soon.** means "I have to travel..."

But is it possible to combine the two?

**3 I've got to travel a lot in my job for the last two years.** - what would it mean?

I have had possibilities to travel for the last two year.

or

I have been obliged to travel for the last two year.

Comment: #3 *I've got to travel a lot in my job for the last two years* is imho "awkward", but it can ***only*** be the past tense version of #1. The past tense of #2 is *I've **had** to travel a lot in my job for the last two years.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done, you've created a garden path sentence.  As you read it you see "I've got to" so you understand it means "I have a current obligation".  Then you get to the end and there is a phrase which means in a period leading up to the present, and not current.  So the interpretation you had of the meaning of "I've got to" must have been wrong.

This means that the reader or listener has to backtrack and change their interpretation.  This causes confusion and misunderstanding.

It is called a "garden path" sentence from the expression "lead someone up the garden path", which means to give misleading clues or signals (defn from google) The structure "I've got to" signals "obligation" but that is misleading, and it is only from context that appears *later* is the correct interpretation realised.

Garden path sentences are grammatical, but should be avoided. (except in jokes)

Comment: OK. So, what does this mean " I've got to travel a lot in my job for the last two years."? a) I have had possibilities to travel for the last two year. b) I have been obliged to travel for the last two year.

Comment: It is a particularly (even *pathologically*) bad way to express (a)